# What “probable” means in two-sorted set theory?

Tags: logic, set-theory, type-theory

I’m reading an nlab article [two-sorted set theory](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/two-sorted+set+theory).

It is written that

> There are a number of ways to present a set theory; one of the most basic decisions when it comes to presenting a set theory is whether the probable sets and probable elements should be regarded as the same kind of objects, as in unsorted set theory, or as fundamentally different objects, as in two-sorted set theory.

What do “**probable** sets” and “**probable** elements” mean?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I think you should read it as meaning "able to be probed (i.e., understood)" and not "likely".

Comment: IMO it is simply badly written... it seems that the intention of the author is to refer to an unspecified object that may be a set or may be not.